# Bitcoin over Tor and man in the middle attack: risks mitigated yet?

Tags: security, tor

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6079.pdf) explains how combining Bitcoin and Tor creates an attack vector. A man in the middle can control the information flow between all users who connect over Tor. This paper is from 2014. Has this sort of risk been mitigated by new engineering yet?